# Print newline at the end of printing array using loop using escape sequence in c

Tags: c

Say I have the following code to print out the array a[n] in C:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

What I want to do is to print the array giving a " " between two consecutive array element and end it with a newline but I want to avoid writing the printf statement twice. Can I do it somehow using some escape sequence? What is the simplest way?

Comment: Though there is an answer with ternary operator, your code with two `printf()` is clearer and better in terms of single iteration complexity.

Answer (score 4):

One of the way would be to use Ternary operator like:

```
printf("%d%c", a[i], i==n-1? '\n': ' ');
```

Which means you print your array element and after that you print either a space if i is not equal to (array size - 1)* or a new line character when you get last element of the array to print.

* Since array index starts from 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx).

```
printf("%d%c", a[i], (i != n-1) ? ' ' : '\n');
```